# How to find out if transcoding and remuxing between certain codecs & formats is possible for a specific build of ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm making a program that utilizes ffmpeg for remuxing and transcoding video files. I want to use `ffmpeg -codecs` and `ffmpeg -formats` (or any other commands available via ffmpeg) to check what formats and codecs I can remux and transcode between. I'm not sure I understand the output correctly so here's my questions:

1. If the output from `ffmpeg -codecs` says that it has decoding support for codec A and encoding support for codec B, does that mean that I can transcode from codec A to codec B? Or do both of them have to have both de and encoding support? Also, when are the "Lossy compression" and "Lossless compression" flags relevant?
2. Almost the same question for remuxing: if the output from `ffmpeg -formats` says that it has demuxing support for format A and muxing support for format B, does that mean that I can remux from format A to format B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes. To transcode from A to B, one needs to decode A and encode to B.
2. Similarly, yes.